# Can you manipulate images stored on aws S3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, imagemagick

My current process: I have a file uploader, that lets users upload images. The images are uploaded to my server. My server then creates 10 thumbnails. These images are then sent to S3.
This is obviously not the fastest solution, which leads to my question: A better solution would be to have the files upload directly to S3 (which I know is possible)... and then create the thumbnails from there.. is it possible to create the thumbnails on images stored in S3?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is 'no'. Look at S3 as at some big refrigerator: you can for sure put some food in it and take it away later, but it'd feel kinda weird cooking within that fridge. )

Comment: So the way I am doing it is the best (indeed only) way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

2 years after.... Lambda is here!

From official page [Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/es/lambda/)

> "You can trigger an AWS Lambda function to automatically create a
>   thumbnail when an image is uploaded to Amazon S3"